# C++ aggregate initialiser behaviour with data array

Tags: c++, data-structures, aggregate-initialization

When altering the order of data array, it seems like `data`is always the one got initialized by the aggregate initializer(not `alter`). Why?

```
struct SqList
{
   ElemType alter[MAXSIZE];
   ElemType data[MAXSIZE];//swap order here
   int Length;
};
```

Isn't the compiler shall treat the first valid memory block as an initializer target?

First of all, I have a SqList class and an overloaded operator<< to print the content.

```
struct SqList
{
    ElemType data[MAXSIZE];
    ElemType alter[MAXSIZE];
    int Length;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const SqList& sql)
{
    for(auto i:sql.data)
        os<<i<<" ";
    os<<"\n";

     for(auto i:sql.alter)
        os<<i<<" ";
    os<<"\n";
    return os;
}
```

In main(), the instance of SqList is created with aggregate initializer

```
int main()
{
    SqList s{1,2,3,4,5};
    cout<<s;
}
```

It is interesting to see that whether if I swap the order of `data` and `alter` in `SqList`, `data` always got initialized with `{1,2,3,4,5}`

[Here](https://github.com/chegJH/poststack/blob/master/SqList.cpp) is the code if you are interested.

[compiler explore](https://godbolt.org/z/L4NbTa)

Comment: Since you're using C++ you really should be using `std::vector` and steer well away from fixed-length C arrays.

Comment: If you want control over where those values go, implement a constructor. You're asking a lot of C++ here to know what you want.

Comment: @tadman there is nothing wrong with using fixed arrays in C++. However, it is preferable to use `std::array` for them, instead of the older C syntax.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You say there's "nothing wrong" and yet all I see on Stack Overflow are cases of where people overflow the array, fail to initialize members properly, and otherwise mess up things that `std::vector` will do for you automatically.

Comment: Well, the original purpose of those lines was mean to be a post-reading practice of some data-structure textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I swap the order of data and alter in `SqList`, `data` always got initialized with `{1,2,3,4,5}`

No, that's not the observed behavior. See e.g those two versions: https://godbolt.org/z/VTeheX vs https://godbolt.org/z/bkA8zs

While you swap the lines in the class declaration, in the definition of the overload of `operator<<` your code always prints `data` before `alter` and the outputs (not to mention the warnings) of the two versions are different.

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting the result you have. But somehow I end with creating this question. And the warning goes away with this ```SqList s{{0,1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5},5};```